# scipy p-value returns 0.0

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

Using a 2 sample Kolmogorov Smirnov test, I am getting a p-value of 0.0.

```
>>>scipy.stats.ks_2samp(dataset1, dataset2)
(0.65296076312083573, 0.0)
```

Looking at the histograms of the 2 datasets, I am quite confident they represent two different datasets.  But, really, p = 0.0?  That doesn't seem to make sense.  Shouldn't it be a very small but positive number?

I know the return value is of type numpy.float64.  Does that have something to do with it?

EDIT:
data here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jpixhz0pcybyh1t/data4stack.csv

```
scipy.version.full_version
'0.13.2'
```

Comment: Numbers smaller than some threshold cannot be distinguished from 0 by floating-point types.  That threshold varies with the type, but there's always a threshold, and apparently your p-value is below it, so it shows up as zero.

Comment: @BrenBarn But how small is the threshold in the case of scipy? P=0 isn't very satisfying. I am looking for a more accurate statement like P<1E-293.

Comment: Pretty sure you're not going to get anything that small.  It may vary by your platform, but I think the smallest you'll get with numpy is on the order of 1E-16.  You can look at [`numpy.finfo`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.finfo.html).

Comment: I think the answer here is: really really.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, the probability is **very** small:

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint ([(i, scipy.stats.ks_2samp(dataset1, dataset2[:i])[1]) 
...                for i in range(200,len(dataset2),200)])
[(200, 3.1281733251275881e-63),
 (400, 3.5780609056448825e-157),
 (600, 9.2884803664366062e-225),
 (800, 7.1429666685167604e-293),
 (1000, 0.0),
 (1200, 0.0),
 (1400, 0.0),
 (1600, 0.0),
 (1800, 0.0),
 (2000, 0.0),
 (2200, 0.0),
 (2400, 0.0)]
```

Comment: which of these is the true p-value?

Comment: @GWarner As you can see above, the more points you use to calculate the correlation, the lower the p-value; once  1,000 points is used, the p-value is below the threshold of being distinguished from 0.0. So the answer to your question is
"The true p-value for correlation between all the points in those 2 datasets is less than 7.1429666685167604e-293."